# How to find the differential of a series? And use it as a Substitution to solve the heat equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, substitution

I have a question that says to solve the heat equation by substituting in
 $$\phi(x,t) = \frac{a_0(t)}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n(t)\cos(\frac{n\pi}{L} x)$$

I presume I must take the partial derivatives of this to be able to solve the heat equation. I should then have a ordinary differential equation for $a_n$.

how would I solve/find this?

Answer (score 0):

If a series is wel-behaving then its okay to interchange the differentiation operator and the summation. So, substitute, differentiate, use the Fourier trick to get DE for a specific $a_n$, solve.